# Upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, ppa

While upgrading to ubuntu 20.04
It shows this

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
This was likely caused by
- Protea software packages not provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool ppa purge from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again
one of this applies then please report this bug using the command ubuntu bug ubuntu-release upgrader-core ina terminal. it you way to investigate this you thing dist upgrade will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at matulog and apt.log
```

Please help how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have any problems following the instructions? "Please use the tool ppa purge from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA"?